# How to handle complex file names simply and write two file name rules into code?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a problem with making filename rules in Python image scraper.
Roughly there're two types of image URLs from a site.

First, src="https://cdn2.ettoday.net/images/5694/5694939.jpg"

This one I can split like this:

```
file_name = image_url.split('/')[-1]
```

Then, I can get the filename as I wanted.

> 5694939.jpg

---

Second, this one seems complicated.

src="https://scontent-tpe1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/160617071_1533135443546936_5774762828455542817_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=_qmfrLffEHEAX9MION0&_nc_ht=scontent-tpe1-1.xx&oh=1a66da48cab3dfefa7847d14a88e1099&oe=60F0936C"

Let's say I only want part of it and the ideal result would be like

> 5774762828455542817_n.jpg

How to split this complicated URL and how to make two or more rules for different image URLs?

Comment: perhaps using regex `re` library could be useful here

Comment: Maybe yes, but sadly I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try splitting first on "/" and then on "?" and then on "_"

```
>>> url = 'https://scontent-tpe1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/160617071_1533135443546936_5774762828455542817_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=_qmfrLffEHEAX9MION0&_nc_ht=scontent-tpe1-1.xx&oh=1a66da48cab3dfefa7847d14a88e1099&oe=60F0936C'
>>> filename = url.split("/")[-1]
>>> filename
'160617071_1533135443546936_5774762828455542817_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=_qmfrLffEHEAX9MION0&_nc_ht=scontent-tpe1-1.xx&oh=1a66da48cab3dfefa7847d14a88e1099&oe=60F0936C'
>>> filename = filename.split("?")[0]
>>> filename
'160617071_1533135443546936_5774762828455542817_n.jpg'
>>> filename = filename.split("_")
>>> filename = filename[0] if len(filename)==1 else "_".join(filename[-2:])
>>> filename
'5774762828455542817_n.jpg'
```

or a two liner would be:

```
filename = url.split("/")[-1].split("?")[0].split("_")
filename = filename[0] if len(filename)==1 else "_".join(filename[-2:])
```

this will give `'5774762828455542817_n.jpg'` as the output

Comment: Oh, thanks. Is there any way to only get "5774762828455542817_n.jpg" ?

Comment: @Peters7 edited my answer to get only "5774762828455542817_n.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard library `urllib` for this task. The library provides the function `urlparse` to parse the *URL*.  But you'd still have to split the path to only get the file name.

```py
import urllib

path = urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path
file_name = path.split('/')[-1]
```

You can also use the external library `yarl` which provides an extensive *URL* class, which has the attribute `name` with which you can excess the file name directly.

```py
import yarl

file_name = yarl.URL(url).name
```

To only get `5774762828455542817_n.jpg` for this particular *URL* you can split it and concatenate the two last items again.

```py
>>> '_'.join(file_name.split('_')[-2:])
'5774762828455542817_n.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), which will serve your purpose.

```
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

image_url = "https://scontent-tpe1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/160617071_1533135443546936_5774762828455542817_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=_qmfrLffEHEAX9MION0&_nc_ht=scontent-tpe1-1.xx&oh=1a66da48cab3dfefa7847d14a88e1099&oe=60F0936C"
data = urlparse(image_url)               
print(os.path.basename(data.path)) # Output: 160617071_1533135443546936_5774762828455542817_n.jpg
```